# Java web start application won't fire events

Tags: java, code-injection, java-web-start

I'm injecting my agent to a java application in order to get events out.
When I do this via a Jar like this :

```
java -agentpath:..\JavaAgent" -Djia.port=4444:4460 -jar app.jar
```

It all works perfect.

But when I do it via web start like this :

```
SET JAVAWS_VM_ARGS=-agentpath:..\JavaAgent -Djia.port=4444:4460 
javaws app.jnlp
```

(which runs the same jar)

It's not working.

When I look at the logs I see that the issue has to do with events that are been triggered.
In my injected code I have a `AWTEventListener` that I register like this :

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(this,AWTEvent.WINDOW_EVENT_MASK);
```

And it works when I ran the jar, I get all the events I registered for which are 
window opened and window closed.
But when I ran it with web start the same code and the same events are not triggered.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Edit your question and include the contents of `app.jnlp`.